# Why the box4 can't be close to box1 with the css?

Tags: html, css

I want box4 and box1 be close to each other ,why there is a gap between them?
I have floated box4 on the left,why it can't lay on the left?

```css
  
              
     div.box{
        width:640px;
        height:500px;
        margin:0 auto;
        }
    div.box1{
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: red;
        float:left;
        }
    div.box2{
        width:140px;
        height:140px;
        background-color: blue;
        float:left;
        } 
    div.box3{
        width:140px;
        height:300px;
        background-color: yellow;
        float:right;
        }
    div.box4{
        width:250px;
        height:300px;
        background-color: green;
        float:left;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box1">box1
        </div>
        <div class="box2">box2
        </div>
        <div class="box3">box3
        </div>
        <div class="box4">box4
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What i got is as below:
[image]

What i want to get is as below:
[image]
How to fix it?
As to Leo the lion's answer,two problems remains:
1.Why my css can't make box4 be close to box1 ,which factor result in that?
Please give more explains in detail.
2.In Leo the lion's answer,two lines added:

```
    top:108px;
    position:absolute;
```

I knew what `position:absolute;` mean here ,`top:108px;` here confused me ,why can't set `top:100px;` ,the height of box1 is just 100px??

Comment: Because of height of box 2..If its ok for you then use position:absoulte and top.

Comment: just a workaround https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/gwc1tLyz/

Comment: Two problems for Leo the lion to answer.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Q1 - The [precise rules for floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#float-rules) point 5 says that "The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document." . i.e. the top of box 4 must not be above the top of box 3. Q2 - Add 8px for the body's top margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.box4 {
   margin-top: -40px;
   width: 250px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: green;
   float: left;
}
```

add  margin-top: -40px;

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give `flexbox` a try:

## Version 1

using `flex-direction: column;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div,
body {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.box {
  max-width: 640px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -moz-box-orient: vertical;
     -moz-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
div.box1 {
  width: 78%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100px;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
          flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}
div.box2 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -webkit-order: 3;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;
      -ms-flex-order: 3;
          order: 3;
  width: 22%;
  min-height: 140px;
  background-color: blue;
}
div.box3 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
  width: 22%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 300px;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 300px;
          flex: 1 1 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
div.box4 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5;
  -webkit-order: 4;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 5;
      -ms-flex-order: 4;
          order: 4;
  width: 22%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 300px;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 300px;
          flex: 1 1 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">box1
  </div>
  <div class="box2">box2
  </div>
  <div class="box3">box3
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="box4">box4
  </div>
</div>
```

## Version 2

using `flex-direction:row` (default), a spacer and negative margin (similar to the float solution). The advantages over the float solution:

1. it adjusts the bottoms of `.box3` and `.box4`
2. it's responsive

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div,
body {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.box {
  max-width: 640px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.box1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 78%;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 78%;
          flex: 1 1 78%;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100px;
}
div.box2 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 22%;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 22%;
          flex-basis: 22%;
  min-height: 140px;
  background-color: blue;
}
div.box3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 22%;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 22%;
          flex: 0 1 22%;
  margin-top: -70px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
div.box4 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 22%;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 22%;
          flex: 0 1 22%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.spacer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 0;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 0;
          flex: 1 1 0
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">box1
  </div>
  <div class="box2">box2
  </div>
  <div class="box3">box3
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="box4">box4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To make simple problem complicated.

Comment: `flexbox` addresses and solves quite a few layout problems. The only problem it has at this point is the vendor prefixes, but that will be *fixed* after it becomes standard (adopted by W3C). Right now, all one needs to do is use the already widely adopted syntax and parse it with an [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) tool.